# When are Javascript events executed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, language-agnostic

When I look at JS code like:

```
socket = new WebSocket(server);

socket.onopen = function (evt) 
{
        // STUFF
};
```

I'm always a little bit confused. If you wrote something like that in any other language, there would be a very huge chance of the `onopen` 'eventhandler' being bound AFTER the connection to `server` already being established, causing you to miss the `onopen` event. Even if first line was executed asynchronously by the Javascript interpreter, there was still a slight chance of being too late on the second line.

Why does the above code run fine in Javascript while in C# (for example) it should be written as:

```
WebSocket socket = new WebSocket();

socket.onopen = new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Open);

socket.Connect(server);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike most other languages, Javascript is strictly single-threaded.
While your code is running, nothing else can happen.

`onopen` cannot fire until control returns to the event loop (after the synchronous portion of that code has finished).

Note that this is true because `onopen` is fired in response to an asynchronous event (in this case, a socket).
If it were raised synchronously, that would not be true; to fix this, code that synchronously raises events used with this pattern should raise the event asynchronously in `process.nextTick`.

Comment: That its single-threaded doesnt mean it cannot execute events immediately, it could just call them from the same thread (like C# does). But you seem to suggest that events are delayed untill the code is idle? Interesting.. That would explain a lot..

Comment: @Joshua: A C# socket class is very likely to raise events on the thread pool (or on an IO completion port thread).  Node.js cannot.

Comment: Yes; any asynchronous action in Javascript (including `setTimeout`) cannot happen while code is running.  This is a direct consequence of its single-threaded nature.

Comment: I think another relevant property not mentioned yet is lack of "preemptive" multitasking within the JS runtime.

Comment: @SLaks I'm thinking you mean that while the `setTimeout()` runs, the code in the function supplied to it only runs later. The current block of code, including the call the `setTimeout()`, has to finish before more code gets pulled off the event queue to run, including the code inside the function.

Comment: We have multiple parallel execution paths across the event listeners. We have to keep this in mind, we can not be certain of their order of execution. In some sense these are parallel threads, executed sequentially just like multitasking on a single-processor computer. The difference, and the only thing we can be sure is that one handler is never suspended mid-execution to run another.

Answer (score 0):

a DIY version might be easier to visualize than a black-box native function:

```
function Sock(url){
  this.init=function(){
        this.url=url;
        this.onopen.call(this, {name:"open", url:url, dt: +new Date});
  } .bind(this);

  setTimeout(this.init, 0);  

}

socket = new Sock("123");

socket.onopen = function (evt) {
          alert( JSON.stringify(evt, null, "\t") );
};
```

It should be a lot more obvious why this works than why new Socket(server) works...